# Beagle Bone Black swapped I2C busses

Tags: beagleboneblack, i2c, archlinux-arm

We are developing extension board for BBB. It contains I2C RTC clock chip MCP79412. Chip is connected to I2C1 (pins P9.17,P9.18). I can't see any device on i2c-1, but I found chip EEPROM on i2c-2. When I connect it to I2C2 (P9.19,P9.20) I can access eeprom using capemgr loaded driver on bus i2c-1.

It looks like something swaped busses 1 and 2. I'm using Arch Linux with Kernel 3.8.13-35.

My uEnv.txt

```
optargs=loglevel=3 coherent_pool=1M capemgr.enable_partno=BB-UART1,BB-UART2,BB-UART4,BB-I2C1,BB-ADC
```

What could cause this strange behavior?

Comment: That's interesting. Did you have a question?

Comment: Question is why is that happening?